# Is it possible to access variables from App.vue in other components in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

I have an app in Vue.js where I have an App.vue like this:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',

 data() {
    return {
      user: null,
    }
  },

  methods: {
       getUser() {
        axios 
        .get(`auth/user/`)
        .then(response => {
          this.user=response.data.pk
        })
      }
  },

  beforeMount() {
    this.getUser();
  },
}
</script>
```

Can I somehow access user variable from other components? how should i export and import it in order to succeed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could:

1. Pass it down as a [prop](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html)

   - Note: To mutate it from a child component you should [emit an event](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html) that tells the root to update it. Don't attempt to mutate it directly in the child.
2. Use [Provide/Inject](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/provide-inject.html)
3. Move `user` to a shared state solution like [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) or [Pinia](https://pinia.vuejs.org/)

Answer (score 1):

4. `$root.someVariable`

Works in Vue 2, didn't test in 3.